# URL rewrite stopped working with https URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2, ssl-certificate

I am developing a PHP based website. I made it live with HTTP URL and URL rewriting.

let suppose my domain is www.abc.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&current_event=$1 [L]
```

And I access my site as `http://www.abc.com/article` it works fine.
Now my client installed SSL certificates on server and I want to change URL to HTTPS but accessing `https://www.abc.com/article` gives me 404 error.

Please guide me how can I make my above rules work with HTTP/HTTPS both.

Comment: are you able to browse `https://www.abc.com` ?

Comment: @RunishKumar yes `https://www.abc.com` is working.